# Jbpm 6 - number of transferred bytes cannot be negative

Tags: jboss, jbpm, kie

Im trying to build a kiecontainer from a remote repository in my "Server";

```
String url  = "http://Server:8080/jbpm-console/maven2/pt/powergrid/UtilityOperationProcesses/1.0/UtilityOperationProcesses-1.0.jar";
    ReleaseIdImpl releaseId = new ReleaseIdImpl("pt.powergrid", "UtilityOperationProcesses", "1.0");
    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    ks.getResources().newUrlResource(url);
    KieContainer kieContainer = ks.newKieContainer(releaseId);
```

But i have this exception:

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: number of transferred bytes cannot be negative
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you get this error if it cannot find the jar, you should configure the maven repo where it can find it, either by adding it in your HOME_FOLDER/.m2/settings.xml or passing where to find your custom settings.xml using -Dkie.maven.settings.custom=CUSTOM_LOCATION_HERE/settings.xml

For example, take a look at https://github.com/krisv/jbpm-evaluation-examples/tree/master/kjar-from-guvnor